# Practical usage of `set -k` option in bash

Tags: bash, shell

When do we use `set -k` option in bash?

[Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins) says,

> All arguments in the form of assignment statements are placed in the environment for a command, not just those that precede the command name.

I understand what the option does, but could not imagine when we need it.

Comment: Correct perception. The `-k` allows us to run 30 year old shell scripts without the need to refactor them.  Pass temporary environment variables using the prefix syntax instead: `var1=x var2=y command ...`

Answer (score 15):

You can basically use it anytime you want to "inject" the environment variables passed into a shell script (as arguments) as if they were set within the environment via `export`, but without having to have them permanently reside in `export`'s list prior to running commands.

**NOTE:** There's also the long form of the `-k` switch, `set -o keyword`.

#### Example

```
$ cat cmd1.bash 
#!/bin/bash

echo $VARCMD
```

Now if I `set -k`:

```
$ set -k; ./cmd1.bash VARCMD="hi"; set +k
hi
```

But if I just were to run the above script:

```
$ ./cmd1.bash 

$
```

#### What's export doing?

```
$ help export
...
Marks each NAME for automatic export to the environment of subsequently
executed commands.  If VALUE is supplied, assign VALUE before exporting.
...
```

So if we were to add `export | grep VAR` to our script like so:

```
$ cat cmd2.bash 
#!/bin/bash

echo $VARCMD
export | grep VAR
```

And we ran our above tests again:

```
$ set -k; ./cmd2.bash VARCMD="hi"; set +k
hi
declare -x VARCMD="hi"
```

But without `set -k`:

```
$ ./cmd2.bash 

$
```

So `set -k` is allowing us to temporarily export variables in mass.

#### Another example

```
$ cat cmd3.bash 
#!/bin/bash

echo $VARCMD1
echo $VARCMD2
export | grep VAR
```

When we set multiple variables they're all exported:

```
$ set -k; ./cmd3.bash VARCMD1="hi" VARCMD2="bye"; set +k
hi
bye
declare -x VARCMD1="hi"
declare -x VARCMD2="bye"
```

#### So then it's just injecting all the environment variables?

No `-k` is doing a very explicit thing here. It's only exporting variables that were included on the command line when a command was executed.

#### Example

Say I set this variable:

```
$ VARCMD1="hi"
```

Now when we run the same command omitting `VARCMD1="hi"`:

```
$  set -k; ./cmd3.bash VARCMD2="bye"; set +k

bye
declare -x VARCMD2="bye"
```

#### But why does this exist?

I found this source which explains a bit about this feature, titled: "Keyword Parameter Assignment Strings". **NOTE:** The source URL uses an IP address so I cannot link to it directly here on SE.

```
http://140.120.7.21/OpenSystem2/SoftwareTools/node16.html
```

> When programming in any language, the variable and its value passing is critical for writing reliable code. Beside the integer and array variable types, all other shell variables accept strings as their values. When talking about shell programming language, to be consistent, we prefer the phrase "keyword parameter". Here are a few points to watch out when assigning values to keyword parameters:
>
> - To avoid any unexpected effect, always place parameter assignment substring in front of a command string.
>
>   In the B shell, the assigned values of keyword parameters will get stored in (local) shell variables. In bash and ksh, the keyword parameter assignment strings preceding command will not be stored in the shell variables. They only affect the immediate subprocess forked to execute the current command. A line of keyword parameters assignment strings alone does get stored in the (local) shell variables. Keyword parameter assignment strings may also appear as arguments to the alias, declare, typeset, export, readonly, and local builtin commands. [Section 3.4 of Bash Reference Manual]
> - The keyword parameter assignment strings will be treated as arguments for the command to be executed, if they are placed after the command name.
> - The keyword parameters may be manipulated by the set command.

Comment: In this link, http://ss64.com/bash/set.html, for `set -k` they have given `-o keyword` besides the `-k` option. Does that mean something?

Comment: @Ramesh - `set -o keyword` is the long form of `set -k`. See `help set | grep -- '-k'`.

Comment: ah ok. I was scratching my head for a long time trying to understand why there are 2 options. As usual perfect answer :)

Comment: `./cmd.bash VARCMD=hi` needs `set -k` to get it to work exactly the way `VARCMD=hi ./cmd.bash` does without the `set -k`. Guess the OP's specific question is around the need for bash to support the `./cmd.bash VARCMD=hi` form

Comment: @1_CR - good point. I believe it has to do with style more than anything, I'll see if I can find an actual source though.

Comment: @1_CR - see updates.

Comment: Please focus on the *alternative* for `-k`: prefix notation.

Answer (score 9):

Any practical usage of `set -k` is likely just personal style. Some - perhaps those who like programming languages that offer the ability to use keyword arguments in function calls, or those few people who like the `dd` command's syntax - may prefer

```
set -k
...
command var1=val1 var2=val2
```

to

```
var1=val1 var2=val2 command
```

The actual reason the option exists in some shells is explained in the [rationale for the set command in the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/set.html#tag_04_127_18):

```
The following set flags were omitted intentionally with the following rationale:

The -k flag was originally added by the author of the Bourne shell to make it easier
for users of pre-release versions of the shell. In early versions of the Bourne shell
the construct
    set name=value
had to be used to assign values to shell variables.
```